# How do I un-merge a shape layer in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How do I un-merge a shape layer in photoshop that was copied from illustrator as a group, but when I paste the grouped shapes in photoshop as a shape layer, It becomes merged, and I cannot un-merge it into separate shape layers?[[Illustrator view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7x71.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/620hO.png)

I tried to look for the Un-merge button so I can convert the merged shape into indevideual shape layers in Photoshop

Answer (score 1):

You can save an Illustrator file as a PSD (Photoshop Document) to preserve the separate shape layers when transferring the artwork from Illustrator to Photoshop.

1. In Adobe Illustrator, open the file you want to transfer to Photoshop.
2. Go to the "File" menu and choose "Export As."
3. In the Format drop-down menu, select "Photoshop (PSD)" as the file format.
4. Click the "Save" button.

Illustrator will then save the file as a PSD, preserving the separate layers. You can open the saved PSD file in Photoshop, and each shape will be on its own layer, allowing you to edit them individually.

Comment: +1 yes. Also another possibility is to place an AI file in Photoshop as a Smart Object. That way, the Smart Object will open Illustrator for editing if you double click on the Smart Object layer.